# mapping List<Object> to JSONArray of JSONObject for REST call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I retrieve the result of the a JPQL JOIN operation over multiple entities as `List<Object>`.

Then I put that `List<Object>` type in the REST API which will be converted to a JSONArray of JSONArrays :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/item/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> getProductsWithItemsByUserID(@PathVariable Long id) {
        List<Object> result= null;
        result= productAndItemServiceImpl.getProductsWithItemsByUserID(id);
        if (result== null)
            return new  ResponseEntity<List<Object>> (HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Object>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

But I wanted to produce a JSONArray of JSONObject for this REST API.
How can I achieve this with manual mapping in Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class (I will name it `ProductDTO` here) that contains all the fields that your query returns. Map the Objects into objects of that new class and return the following:

```
return new ResponseEntity<List<ProductDTO>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Instances of ProductDTO should then be automatically mapped into the appropriate JSON structure.